# Tests fail when trying to list kubernetes CRD objects using ListOptions' Limit

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, client-go, kubernetes-go-client

I'm trying to list CRD objects using Limit as follows:

```
...
someObjList := v1alpha1.SomeObjList{}
_ = cl.List(ctx, &someObjList, client.InNamespace(lib.Namespace), &listOptions)
```

When testing, I add 25 objects to a fake client then call the list function with a Limit of 10:

```
opts := client.ListOptions{
    Limit: 10,
}
result, _ := lib.List(context.Background(), opts)
assert.Equal(t, 10, len(result))
```

But the test fails with:

```
assertion failed: 10 (int) != 25 (int)
```

I'm not sure if I need to add something specific to the fake client in order to make this work. This is the current client I use in tests:

```
func makeClient(t *testing.T, clusterState ...runtime.Object) client.Client {
    scheme := runtime.NewScheme()
    schemeBuilder := runtime.SchemeBuilder{
        ...
    }
    err := schemeBuilder.AddToScheme(scheme)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    return fake.NewClientBuilder().
        WithScheme(scheme).
        WithRuntimeObjects(clusterState...).
        Build()
}
```

Comment: Turned out that the fake client-go ignores the `limit` parameter as mentioned here: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/793

So to write pagination tests we need to use a real API server which envtest provides: https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/envtest